# Super Kamiokande experiment with atmospheric neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos

Why did the super Kamiokande experiment see half the rate of atmospheric muon neutrinos from below than from above, but the same rates from electron neutrinos? It seems like it has to do with interactions with electron neutrinos and electrons, but i don't know how. Source: Particle Physics - Martin, Shaw.

I found the question [Muon Neutrinos vs Electron neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188014/muon-neutrinos-vs-electron-neutrinos), but it's about solar neutrinos.

Comment: can you give a link for the experimental number you are quoting? Super Kamiokande  afaik from the wiki  does also sun and atmospheric neutrinos so the answer  in the link should be ok ( for atmospheric neutrios)

Comment: @annav it's stated in Particle Physics - Martin, Shaw. The authors just state that the numbers of muon neutrinos above vs below are different, but the numbers of electron neutrinos above vs below are the same

Comment: they are talking then of atmospheric neutrinos, the ones created by interactions in the atmosphere all around the earth. the link you give talks of atmospheric neutrinos not sun neutrinos.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the atmospheric neutrinos are produced via pion decay chain:

$\pi^- \rightarrow \mu^- + \overline{\nu}_\mu$,

$\mu^- \rightarrow e^- + \nu_\mu + \overline{\nu}_e.$

As the end result of pion decay, two muon neutrinos and one electron neutrino are produced (1:2 ratio). See picture below for intuitive view. This is for the muon neutrinos from above the detector.

Regarding the neutrinos arriving to the detector below: they are created in atmosphere other side of the world and travel through Earth thousands of kilometers, and the [neutrino oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillations) effects are important. Half of the muon neutrinos oscillate (or transform) to electron neutrinos in-flight. The characteristic length of oscillation of these neutrinos is order of hundreds of kilometers, so the above-arriving neutrinos (which are created approx. 15 km above the detector) have had no time to transform to other neutrinos.

[image: Pion decay in atmosphere]